# How to swap two values in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton

In this visualforce page there are two inputs and one button. How to swap the values in given two inputs from input-1 to input-2 and input-2 to input-1. Please provide suggestions

**I tried the above code**

VF code:-

```
<apex:page controller="Swap_Values">
<apex:form >
<apex:outputLabel >Enter Value</apex:outputLabel>
<apex:inputText value="{!x}"/>
<apex:inputText value="{!y}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Swap" action="{!SV}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex code:-

```
public class Swap_Values {

    public String y { get; set; }

    public String x { get; set; }

    public PageReference SV() {
        x=y;
        y=x;
        return null;
    }

}
```

Please provide suggestions to do this swap functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you do `x=y;` you're overwriting the value stored into `x`, so its previous value is lost, then `y=x;` just store into `y` its own value.
In order to swap values, you must save the value into a temporary variable:

```
String tmp = x;
x = y;
y = tmp;
```

Comment: Thank you very much !